# fullPage.js move div down

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js

I want to move a div down like the green iphone on this [page](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/apple.html) on the third scroll where the green iphone moves to the fourth section.

the evelope comes from this [guy](http://codepen.io/peiche/pen/FLkbq)

I made a fiddle -> `http://jsfiddle.net/4L7kosnz/` <- with a test and my problem.

my code looks like this:

```
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section moveDown" id="section0">
        <div class="envelope">
          <div class="paper"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="section" id="section1">
        <div class="envelope">
            <div class="paper"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my jQuery code:

```
(function() {
  $('#fullpage').fullpage({
    'sectionsColor': ['#2B2735', '#fff', '#fff', '#fff'],
    'navigation': true,
    'navigationPosition': 'right',
    'onLeave': function(index, nextIndex, direction) {
      alert(123);
    }
  });

}).call(this);
```

Comment: What is the problem? Please be more specific.

Comment: @Adam how I can fade the evelope from the first section into the second section like the green iphone on the page i linked